# (AWS) EFS File Sync through VBox

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, amazon-efs

I'm trying to move about 100GB of data from one of my internal hosts up to our new AWS EFS volume.

My first inclination was to use `rsync` to get a trusted copy up to the volume, but I'm looking at somewhere around 8Mb/s and my first copy operation has taken somewhere around 24 full hours.

I read up on EFS File sync, a utility that's supposed to accelerate the copying operations of large datasets.

In the setup, the instructions dictate that I need to use a ESXi Virtual Image to launch a VM appliance that will connect up to AWS. I believe the recommendation is to use a hypervisor that can be assigned a reachable IP, but I only have my workstation to use.

I'm running into trouble configuring the appliance's network, so that it can handshake with the EFS Agent. I tried using a bridged adapter, but my corporate network uses AD and won't assign an IP to the VM.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instructions also say you can use an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) for Amazon EC2 based agent. Why not use that? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/get-started-file-sync.html

Comment: I'm just generally unfamiliar with what that meant. My understanding was that the source of the data would be an EC2 instance, is that incorrect?

Comment: "Deploy a sync agent that can mount your source file system."
Either will work - but you need to have them mount *your* file system. What is your local file system OS?

Comment: I would stick with rsync or compress/archive file then upload. Is it really time sensitive data? Do you need sync long term or just for migration.

Comment: @rodrigoM Running OS X. Behind corporate Firewall. Not sure how they would be able to mount my FS. I'll stick with this rsync for now.